# Team Foundation Server и Ubuntu

Tags: tfs, ubuntu

На работе выдача тасков выполнена через team foundation server, хочу поставить в качестве оси ubuntu, под неё есть вариант? Браузер - неудобно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Здесь](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/morgen/archive/2010/06/07/using-tfs-in-linux-ubuntu.aspx) можно прочитать как это делается. Кратко: tfs ставится как плагин к Eclipse.

Comment: Спасибо, думал что нельзя